# When receiving a letter via 'mailkit', the from field has an incomprehensible set of characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mailkit

In outlook, I send any letter to a contact in the address book. then in my mail client I try to get the from field

`var from = message.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault()?.Address;`

And it contains the following line:

`IMCEAEX-_O=FIRST+20ORGANIZATION_OU=EXCHANGE+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=00037FFE69354E9A@sct-15-20-4755-11-msonline-outlook-80ceb.templateTenant`

How to get the mailbox? not a set of characters?

Everything is described in the section above.

Comment: I suggest you could debug the  `Message.From.Mailboxes` to see if there is other send Email address.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably what the email address looks like in the From header. It looks like that address was mapped from an X400 address to MIME.